# Link to another view using ruby in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a simple CR and trying to put some  link/button(add,edit etc), when the user will click the add it will direct to that view..

Question: How should I indicate which view will be load when I click the specific link/button?

**Index.html.erb**

```
<h1>My First CRUD!</h1>
<%= link_to "Add Page", posts_path %>
<%= link_to "Edit Page", posts_path %>
<%= link_to "Showx Page", posts_path %>
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def addItem
    end
    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end
    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:item, :description)
        end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts
  root "posts#index"
  resources :posts
  root "posts#addItem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare all the root routes that you want in your `routes.rb`, but it'll take just the one that was declared first, it doesn't matter if the definition has some mistake, it won't tell you.

And the route where the `link_to` will redirect is what you declare as second argument (in this case).

In your example you have three `link_to`tags, which are pointing to the same path. If you'd like to make the "Edit" `link_to`redirect to the `posts#edit` method you firstly must create the `edit` method in your `posts_controller` and then add it to your route as:

```
get '/posts/edit/:id', to: 'posts#edit'
```

But in your case as you have `resources :posts` it makes the whole work for you and creates all the routes defined in the `posts#controller`, what resources do is *to map a number of related requests to actions in a single controller*, that's to say;

When Rails application receives a request for:

```
GET /posts/edit/1
```

That's what happen when you go to edit the a certain post by passing the id of `1`, then *it asks the router to map it to a controller action. If the first matching route is*:

```
resources :posts
```

Then Rails dispatchs that request to the edit action on the posts controller with { id: '1' } in params.

Short answer, to create a common `<a>` tag create a `link_to`, add a text to specify to where will this redirect, then the route that you've defined, you can check them by running `rails routes` if you're using Rails 5 or `bin/rake routes` if you're with Rails < 5.

Comment: One last thing, is there any numeric type in form? for example in html, there's number because I want to create a field called price

Comment: Of course yes, you can use the `number_field_tag`, see this and more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for).